# Objective-c integer to string giving random numbers?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm busy working on an iPad application and my web service returns pretty simple JSON data. All seems well and I have other methods doing this same conversion without issue however, I have 1 method that returns a random string when doing a integer -> string conversion.

My userdata object below is a NSDictionary created by the SBJSON parser. The value when debugging of [userdata objectForKey:@"UserID"] is 1.

However when I do this

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [userdata objectForKey:@"UserID"]];
```

The value in userId is or appears to be a random number such as 23425234. I also tried the %d in my format but got the same result.

Comment: Doesn't [userdata objectForKey:] return an object, i.e. not an integer? So you would need a step in between? Or just assign it to NSString *userID straight up?

Comment: What kind of objects do you store in `userdata`?

Comment: @typemismatch: You have a type mismatch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is an object, not an int, you see the address of the object, instead, you can do that:

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [userdata objectForKey:@"UserID"]];
                                                 ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[userdata objectForKey:@"UserID"] intValue]];
```

Or:

```
NSString *userId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [userdata objectForKey:@"UserID"]];
```

object for key is probably NSNumber and not int...

Comment: thanks, I appreciate the extra insight - gotta remember I always get objects back from these things :)